# Rails db column "rank" is now a MySQL keyword

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

A few columns in a rails app I am working with are named "rank" but as of MySQL 8.x "rank()" is now a function. Is there a way to get ActiveRecord in rails to put backticks around every column name when doing queries? That seems to be the only way I can get the queries to work.

Comment: Are you saying you have a table with multiple columns of the same name?

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting/quote_column_name but it defaults to "no quoting" so you'll have to override it. I don't know if it uses this function in all the AR-generated queries.

Comment: Could I see an example of a query you are trying to run?

Comment: No there are multiple tables with the column "rank" which used to work fine until MySQL added the rank() function. Now "rank" is a keyword. The query is run as part of the create() model method. It first does a select query to find a record with the same values.